# How can I repeat output on an excelsheet using php

Tags: php, mysql

Please I have some block of codes below which populates data from database into an excel sheet and download into ones device.. It works just fine for me, except that i want to repeat each data coming out from database 3x, i.e. `John John John` in its rows i.e A1,A2,A3 etc, for all the datas retrieved. Please help coz all I tried failed, like the "IF condition" in between the code-block... Thank You

````
             require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
     //create PHPExcel object
     $excel = new PHPExcel();
     //database connection here
     include_once "db.php";
     //insert some data to PHPExcel object
     $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

     $query =mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from student  WHERE class='".$class."' ");
     $row=4;
     $count=0;
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
              if($count<2)
            {
            $excel->getActiveSheet()

                    ->setCellValue('A'.$row , $data->name)

                     ->setCellValue('B'.$row , $class)   

             ->setCellValue('C'.$row , $data->email)
             ->setCellValue('D'.$row , 'Exam');

     }


     else
     {

     }

             $row++;

             }           $count++;
     // set column dimension/width

     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);

     //make table headers
     $excel -> getActiveSheet()
     ->setCellValue('A1', 'TABLE LISTS/DATA') //this is a title
     ->setCellValue('A3', 'NAME')
     ->setCellValue('B3', 'CLASS')
     ->setCellValue('C3', 'EMAIL')


     //merging the title
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:D1');

     //aligning
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
     //styling
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
     array(
     'font'=>array(
     'size'=>24,
     )
     )
     );

     $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:C3')->applyFromArray(
     array(
     'font'=>array(
     'bold'=>true
     ),
     'borders'=>array(
     'allborders'=>array(
     'style'=> PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
     )
     )
     )
     );

     //redirect to browser (download) instead of saving the result as a file

     //this is for MS Office Excel 2007 xlsx format
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$class._Resultsheet.xlsx");

     //this is for MS Office Excel 2003 xls format
     //header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
     //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"');


     header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

     //write the result to a file
     //for excel 2007 format
     $file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');

     //for excel 2003 format
     //$file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel5');

     //output to php output instead of filename
     $file->save('php://output');

 ?>
 ```
````

Comment: Ok. thank you, will improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question, there is a trick you can do to repeat the rows

```
select * 
from student cross join 
(select "" union all select "" union all select "") repeater
order by student.id
```

sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3349b/269

#### Original Answer

> It works just fine for me, except that i want to repeat each data coming out from database 3x, i.e. John John John in its rows i.e A1,A2,A3 etc, for all the datas retrieved.

Then I suggest you **keep your PHP code unchanged** and get the result you need at a lower level from MySQL, using MySQL [concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Instead of doing that

```
select * from student
```

Do it like this

```
select
    concat(col1, ',', col1, ',', col1) as col1,
    concat(col2, ',', col2, ',', col2) as col2,
    concat(col3, ',', col3, ',', col3) as col3,
    concat(col4, ',', col4, ',', col4) as col4
    --  .....
from student
```

*(change the separator from `","` to space `" "` for the columns you like)*

IMO, I think it's always better to chose doing things at the DB level instead of PHP level. That makes your DB more portable and more independent from the application code, for example you can move a MySQL DB that was working under a PHP application to work under a JAVA application without too much work by the new JAVA developer.

Comment: Concat is for joining 2 or more strings or so.. I dont want to join. I want each repeated data to have its own row on the excel sheet. not joining them in same cell

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood the question, my bad! I will delete it.

Comment: @user74651 Is this what you want ?

Comment: yes please. Ive been finding it difficult achieving that

Comment: @user74651 see the update, it's really simple solution